# How do I create a makefile from a Visual Studio solution file?

Tags: visual-studio, makefile

I have a Visual Studio project that uses a solution file to build it. I want to generate a makefile so that I can build it using the makefile instead of the solution file. (The reason I need to do this in case you are wondering is that I am incorporating my project into a larger software system that uses makefiles to build, and I want to be able to build the whole thing using the makefiles.)

Is there a way to automatically get the information from the Visual Studio solution and convert it into a makefile format, or do I need to do that manually?

Comment: I think that this question is very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/870533/1106459

Comment: @RichardShepherd: They are, but only flag if they are *exact dupes*.  [Because you should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).  In situations like this, I'd suggest (if you have the rep) voting to close as dupe, pointing out the duplicate, and (if egregious) downvoting the question.

Comment: Latest version http://web.archive.org/web/20200309005557/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870533/where-can-i-find-a-tool-to-convert-a-vs-solution-to-a-gcc-makefile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This used to be possible in VC6, it had an option to generate a makefile from a .dsp project file.  No more, the build process has changed too much to make this achievable.

Not a real problem, you can have the makefile invoke the vcbuild.exe tool, it builds a .vcproj project.  Important switches you'll want to use in your makefile:

- /clean: use that in your clean: target
- /rebuild: use in your rebuild: target
- /nocolor: makes build output look battleship gray like other build tools
- /platform: selects the configuration you want to build (e.g: /platform:win32)

For example:

```
vcbuild /platform:win32 example.vcproj release
```

Note that the build system got a major revision in VS2010, you'll use msbuild.exe instead to build the .vcxproj project.

Answer (score 1):

Although I never used it, this might be an [alternative](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300-old/cs1300/bin/dsw2mak). It's rather old and might not work well for new projects. It used to come with mingw but (don't know why) not anymore. *Offtopic: Personally, if the project is not enormous, I would go with manually writing a Makefile.*

Comment: Good advice - Avoid wasting a couple of days on tools for a job that'll take a few hours at most.  They guy who built my first house had one 30 year old table saw and built the whole house iwth it.  I now have at least 10 saws and never build anything.